# Pivot / invert table (but not quite) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem for which I managed to write some working code, but I'd like to see if anyone here could have a simpler / more organized / less ugly / more in-built solution. Sorry for the extremely vague title, but I wasn't able to summarize the issue in one sentence.

**The problem**

Basically I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
  id  foo_col  A  B  C  D
0  x  nothing  2  0  1  1
1  y       to  0  0  3  2
2  z      see  1  3  2  2
```

Now I'd like to transform the columns `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` into `['W1', 'W2', 'W3']`, that would be the first 3 column names (per row) sorted using the numbers in each row.

In this way, the row with id `x` would have `A` (with 2), `C` (with 1), `D` (with 1), `B` (with 0), thus getting `'W1' = 'A'`, `'W2' = 'C'`, `'W3' = 'D'`.

The target DataFrame would then look like this:

```
  id  foo_col W1 W2    W3
0  x  nothing  A  C     D
1  y       to  C  D  None
2  z      see  B  C     D
```

**The rules**

1. Ties can be broken just using alphabetical order (row `x`);
2. If there are less than 3 non-zero `W`s, the ones that are missing will get `None` (row `y`);
3. If there are more than 3 non-zero `W`s, the extra one will not make it in the final DataFrame (row `z`).

**The solution**

```
import pandas as pd
import operator
import more_itertools as mit

# Define starting DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
                        'foo_col': ['nothing', 'to', 'see'],
                        'A': [2, 0, 1],
                        'B': [0, 0, 3],
                        'C': [1, 3, 2],
                        'D': [1, 2, 2]})

print('Original DataFrame')
print(df.to_string())
print()

# Define 'source' and 'target' columns
w_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
w_labels = ['W1', 'W2', 'W3']

# Define function to do this pivoting
def pivot_w(row, columns=w_columns, labels=w_labels):
    # Convert relevant columns of DF to dictionary
    row_dict = row[columns].to_dict()
    # Convert dictionary to list of tuples
    row_tuples = [tuple(d) for d in row_dict.items()]
    # Sort list of tuples based on the second item (the value in the cell)
    row_tuples.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    # Get the sorted 'column' labels
    row_list = [x[0] for x in row_tuples if x[1] != 0]
    # Enforce rules 2 and 3
    if len(row_list) < 3:
        row_list = list(mit.take(3, mit.padnone(row_list)))
    else:
        row_list = row_list[:3]

    # Create a dictionary using the W lables
    output = {i: j for i, j in zip(labels, row_list)}

    return output

# Get DataFrame with W columns and index
df_w = pd.DataFrame(list(df.apply(pivot_w, axis=1)))
# Merge DataFrames on index
df = df.merge(df_w, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
# Drop A, B, C, D columns
df.drop(columns=w_columns, inplace=True)

print('Final DataFrame')
print(df.to_string())
```

Aside for maybe re-using the same variable to store the in-between results in the function, is there anything smarter I could do?

**P.S.** If anyone of you has an idea for a **better/clearer title** please feel free to edit!

Comment: There is minimal value `0` ?

Comment: Congrats on writing a good structured question including a copy and pasteable `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [argsort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308225/2901002) for get top3 columns names, but then is necessary replace positions from `0` values with sorting and `np.where`:

```
w_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
w_labels = ['W1', 'W2', 'W3']

#sorting columns names by values, last are 0 values (because minimal)
arr = np.array(w_columns)[np.argsort(-a, axis=1)]
print (arr)
[['A' 'C' 'D' 'B']
 ['C' 'D' 'A' 'B']
 ['B' 'C' 'D' 'A']]

#sorting values for 0 to last positions and compare by 0
mask = -np.sort(-df[w_columns], axis=1) == 0
print (mask)
[[False False False  True]
 [False False  True  True]
 [False False False False]]

#replace first 3 'columns' by mask to None
out = np.where(mask[:, :3], None, arr[:, :3])
print (out)
[['A' 'C' 'D']
 ['C' 'D' None]
 ['B' 'C' 'D']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=w_labels, index=df.index)
print (df1)
  W1 W2    W3
0  A  C     D
1  C  D  None
2  B  C     D
```

---

```
df = df.drop(w_columns, 1).join(df1)
print (df)
  id  foo_col W1 W2    W3
0  x  nothing  A  C     D
1  y       to  C  D  None
2  z      see  B  C     D
```

If possible need exclude some another value whic is not minimal in all seelcted values is possible repalce it to `NaN`s and for test use `np.isnan`:

```
a = np.where(df[w_columns] != 0, df[w_columns], np.nan)
print (a)
[[ 2. nan  1.  1.]
 [nan nan  3.  2.]
 [ 1.  3.  2.  2.]]

arr = np.array(w_columns)[np.argsort(-a, axis=1)]
mask = np.isnan(np.sort(a, axis=1))

out = np.where(mask[:, :3], None, arr[:, :3])
print (out)

[['A' 'C' 'D']
 ['C' 'D' None]
 ['B' 'C' 'D']]
```

Answer (score 2):

here is one way:

```
l=['W1', 'W2', 'W3']

m=df.set_index(['id','foo_col'])
```

---

```
m=(m.replace(0,np.nan).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3),axis=1).notna().dot(m.columns+',')
 .str[:-1].str.split(',',expand=True))
```

---

```
m.columns=l
m.reset_index()
```

---

```
  id  foo_col W1 W2    W3
0  x  nothing  A  C     D
1  y       to  C  D  None
2  z      see  B  C     D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(df[['A','B','C','D']]
 .stack()
 .loc[lambda x:x!=0]
 .reset_index()
 .sort_values(by=['level_0',0], ascending=False)
 .groupby('level_0').apply(lambda x:x.reset_index())['level_1']
 .reindex([0,1,2],level=1)
 .rename(lambda x:'W'+str(x+1),level=1)
 .unstack())
```

Comment: Please say *WHY* your answer works, not just *HOW* to fix the OP's question.